# PHP and XML - Parsing without result

Tags: php, xml, parsing

In my php script, I try to parse a online - xml file.

That´s how I load it into my script:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
```

Now, I want to make a test output. I try it with

```
echo $xml->title;
```

but there is no result. When I try print_r($xml) I get the right XML file. 
It looks like that:

```
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>testtitle</title>

and so on
```

Why is there no result?

Comment: Try echo $xml->channel->title; OR ptint_r($xml->channel;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the nesting of the elements.

```
<rss>
-> $xml
<channel>
-> $xml->channel
<title>
-> $xml->channel->title
```

So if u use:

```
<?php
echo  $xml->channel->title;
?>
```

That will output your title

Comment: Ah okay, that´s it. I was a bit confused because there was no output. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

//test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>testtitle</title>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

//test.php

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
echo $xml->channel->title;
?>
```